# Inserting values into database using JSP

Tags: ajax, database, jsp

```
<%
      if (MultipartFormDataRequest.isMultipartFormData(request))
      {
         // Uses MultipartFormDataRequest to parse the HTTP request.
         MultipartFormDataRequest mrequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);
         String todo = null;
         if (mrequest != null) todo = mrequest.getParameter("todo");
         if ( (todo != null) && (todo.equalsIgnoreCase("upload")) )
         {
            Hashtable files = mrequest.getFiles();
            if ( (files != null) && (!files.isEmpty()) )
            {
                UploadFile file = (UploadFile) files.get("uploadfile");
                if (file != null) 

                out.println("");

                 //out.println(report1);  
                 String sever = mrequest.getParameter("sever");
                 String ease = mrequest.getParameter("ease");
                 String logo = "C:/uploads/"+file.getFileName();  // Uses the bean now to store specified by jsp:setProperty at the top.
                 String dana = mrequest.getParameter("danalysis");
                 String loc = mrequest.getParameter("loc");
                 String state = mrequest.getParameter("state");
                 String Sr = mrequest.getParameter("Sr");
                 String Doc_ID = mrequest.getParameter("doc");
                 String impact = mrequest.getParameter("impact");
                 String desc = mrequest.getParameter("desc");
                 String ref = mrequest.getParameter("ref");
                 String recom = mrequest.getParameter("recom"); 
                try
                        {
                        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mssg";
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root","");
                        out.println("OK!\n");
                    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("insert into report values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        ps1.setString(1,Doc_ID);
                        ps1.setString(2,Sr);
                        ps1.setString(3,sever);
                        ps1.setString(4,ease);
                        ps1.setString(5,state);
                        ps1.setString(6,loc);
                        ps1.setString(7,desc);
                        ps1.setString(8,impact);
                        ps1.setString(9,dana);
                        ps1.setString(10,logo);
                        ps1.setString(11,recom);
                        ps1.setString(12,ref);

                        int count=ps1.executeUpdate();
                        if(count > 0)
            {
              out.println("successfully inserted");
                          //response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");

            }
            else
                         {
            out.println("error occured");
                     }
                   }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("error in program:-"+e);
            }

                upBean.store(mrequest, "uploadfile");
            }
            else
            {
               out.println("<li>No uploaded files");
            }

   } 
 }

%>
```

In the above code I get all the values also file is uploading but not able to insert these values into database. I think I made a very small mistake, please tell me what is the problem in the above code. This code is working until connection but after prepare statement it's not working.

Comment: provide your problem and stacktrace

Comment: i am not able to insert values into database

Comment: Yes I understand that but what error are you facing when you are running the application? What is the stack trace you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse you have used try and catch block.

In the jsp page life cycle, the jsp page is translated in the servlets. so the code for the database connectivity will be automatically placed in the try catch block.

Just remove the try catch block.